# Node.js: Receiving too many UDP messages at a time, losing them

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, udp

My node server receives about **400 UDP messages** in one second, and it all **works**, and I am able to process all 400 of them.

However, when I start to receive about **700 UDP messages** in one second, **I lose 2-20** of the messages, and they never get parsed :(

I have thought about some **options** here:

1. **Create a queue** of all the socket messages, then consume one-by-one,
   although I'm not sure how to implement this

   - Can't figure out how to implement
2. Find a **setting** in **Node** / Express / dgram socket where i can increase the memory size / buffer size, something like that

   - I couldn't find any settings like this, though :(
3. **Use a different UDP receiver**, stop using node's build in socket UDP receiver

   - Didn't find other receivers

Here's what my UDP sender looks like:

```
var dgram = require("dgram");
var udpserver = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
var seatStateStore = require("./SeatStateStore");

udpserver.on("message",
        function (msg, rinfo)
        {
        seatStateStore.parseMessage(msg.toString());
    });
```

Anyone have any ideas? I couldn't figure out any of the 3 options :/ Can someone help me out?

Node v0.10.29

Express v3.14.0

===============================

## UPDATE / SOLUTION

Here's the code I ended up using (slightly modified @RoyHB 's solution):

```
var dgram = require("dgram");
var udpserver = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
var seatStateStore = require("./SeatStateStore");
var Dequeue = require('dequeue');
var FIFO = new Dequeue();

fetcher();

udpserver.on("message",
        function (msg, rinfo)
        {
           FIFO.push(msg.toString());
        });

udpserver.bind(43278);

function fetcher () {
    while (FIFO.length > 0) 
    {
        var msg = FIFO.shift();
        seatStateStore.parseMessage(msg);
    }
    setImmediate(fetcher); //make this function continuously run
}
```

Comment: Where are the senders from? Are they in the same network? Also note that UDP brings no message delivery guarantees.

Comment: @E_net4 Yeah, I was worried about that as well. The messages are coming from the same server that node is running on. The UDP only get lost, though, when I send a LOT :(

Comment: how much data is being received?

Comment: @LuckyBurger About 700 short messages per second, using UDP

Comment: You're right about suspecting the UDP socket buffer size. It may be that the datagrams are being received faster than the server can handle.

Comment: 700 msgs really isn't that much. I think I would need to see more code to see whats going on.

Comment: Yeah :/ How do I make the UDP socket buffer size bigger? I can't find a setting for that x.x

Comment: You should probably be doing setImmediate within the "message" callback. Otherwise you are pegging your CPU with an infinite loop. Just make sure to have a variable which you can have setImmediate only when the queue has been drained... or use readstreams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a NPM module called [node-dequeue](https://github.com/lleo/node-dequeue/).  I use it a lot for similar situations to yours.

basically,

1. your program pushes received messages onto the end of the queue.
2. an interval timer periodically activates another method or function ( a queue-fetcher) which checks to see if there are messages on the queue and if so, fetches one or more and processes it.
3. Alternatively (maybe better) no timer is used to schedule queue fetches.  Instead the node process.nextTick method is used.

Alternatively, maybe preferably, you can use node process.nextTick to continuously check the queue for messages.

Ideally, seatStateStore.parseMessage would create a new object to asynchronously process one message so that parseMessage returns without delay while the actual message processing continues in the background.  (see bottom of example code )

*I haven't tested the code below, it's meant to illustrate, not to run*

```
var FIFO = require ('dequeue');
var seatStateStore = require("./SeatStateStore");
var dgram = require("dgram");

setInterval(fetcher, 1);

var udpserver = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

udpserver.on("message",
    function (msg, rinfo) {
        FIFO.push(msg);
    }
);

function fetcher () {
    while (FIFO.length > 0) {
        var msg = FIFO.shift();
        seatStateStore.parseMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

** OR (maybe better) **

```
var FIFO = require ('dequeue');
var seatStateStore = require("./SeatStateStore");
var dgram = require("dgram");

fetcher();

var udpserver = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

udpserver.on("message",
    function (msg, rinfo) {
        FIFO.push(msg);
    }
);

function fetcher () {
    while (FIFO.length > 0) {
        var msg = FIFO.shift();
        seatStateStore.parseMessage(msg);
        process.nextTick(fetcher);
    }
}
```

Outline of seatStateProcessor.parseMessage:

```
seatStateProcessor.parseMessage = function (msg) {
    proc = new asyncProcHandler(msg, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            //handle the error
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The problem is likely with the socket buffer size. Not sure i understand how it's supposed to solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

I know there is already an answer to this, but as of today, I found a way to increase the buffer on dgram from the official documentation: [official doc](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html#dgram_socket_setrecvbuffersize_size).

```
socket.setRecvBufferSize(size);
Added in: v8.7.0
size <integer>
Sets the SO_RCVBUF socket option. Sets the maximum socket receive buffer in bytes.

socket.setSendBufferSize(size)
Added in: v8.7.0
size <integer>
Sets the SO_SNDBUF socket option. Sets the maximum socket send buffer in bytes.
```

Usage example:

```
var socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
socket.on("listening", () => {
    socket.setRecvBufferSize(100000000); // 100mb
    socket.setSendBufferSize(100000000); // 100mb
});
```

The default value is 65507

Comment: Actually your answer is the one that i recommend and for me it would be preferred to solve the issue. As the above answers don't solve anything on the problem just add redundant complexity to the code. For any new comers make sure you put these calls in the "listening" event handler

Comment: For reference, the default value depends on the OS and its configuration. For example, on my Raspberry PI it is 163840 and on Ubuntu 18.04 it is 212992.