# Node.js clustering - 1 worker per core slows down main thread?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, cluster-computing

So I am a little concerned with the example code that I am finding online when it comes to node.js clustering, for example:

```
if (cluster.isMaster)
{
    console.log('Initializing...');

    // Fork workers.
    for (let i = 0; i < os.cpus().length; i++)
    {
        cluster.fork();
    }
}
else
{
    doWork();
}
```

For a system that has 4 physical cores, this code will fork 4 times for each core. This means we end up with the Main Thread + 4 worker threads == 5 threads.

This seems like we have one more worker than we can handle! To ensure that the main thread runs normally, shouldn't the code be: `os.cpus().length - 1`, so that we leave one core available for the main thread to work with?

**For my purposes**

I'm running a UDP server where I want half of my workers processing incoming packets, and the other half sending out tons of packets per second inside of a setInterval function.

I dont want any latency between the main thread (which is doing the load balancing)  and the worker threads that process packets coming in, so I want to make sure that the main thread works at 100% speed.

In that case, would I use `os.cpus().length - 1` in my forking for-loop, or would i use `os.cpus().length`?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I noticed there is a a question out there similar to mine, and the answer explains that the main thread usually spends very little time on distribution so leaving one core available for it would likely leave that core idle. I believe this is true for TCP/IP, but in my case I am expecting about 30- 60 packets per second from each client "connected" to my server, so there is going to be a constant flow of packets coming in, which may differ to how TCP/IP traffic looks like.

Comment: How can you assert that one thread occupies one core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the master thread is only a load balancer and is just directing requests to each of the spawned/forked worker threads. So you have one thread per core of your app running + one thread to manage the requests. If you have os.cpus().length - 1 you will not be leveraging all your cpu cores.

Comment: Correct. So normally the main thread wouldn't be doing enough work to justify having its own c ore. However, in my case, where I am expecting a lot of UDP packets coming in every second from each client, wouldn't it be justified at that point?

Comment: Let's say there could be at least 1000 clients sending packets, and they will want to send 30 - 60 packets per second. So about 60,000 per second?

Comment: So that puts me out of depth. This guy was having issues over 400 packets per second and needed to start queuing the packets.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867428/node-js-receiving-too-many-udp-messages-at-a-time-losing-them

My last project was handling 2000 packets (TCP) per second fine with only two cores, and workers spawned for both. But 60k pps is higher than I have experienced.

Comment: Ah I see. My expectations of the packet frequency might be too high, so the actual pps might end up being less than what I'm expecting.

Comment: have you tried to cluster using process management like pm2, since it will handle the load balancing and forking the app?

Comment: @mohammadmohammad I just quickly looked at pm2, and it looks very promising. Thank you for mentioning it, I will dig deeper and explore it.